# Proving an algebraic identity in Mathematica

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I am new to mathematica and I wonder if one cqn prove or get some clue through mathematica about the following identity.
If $0 \leq a_i \leq 1$, then :
$$\sum_1^n\frac{1}{1+a_i}\geq \frac12(n-1) + \frac{1}{1+\prod_1^n a_i}$$
Any help or hints are highly appreciated

Comment: When people want to _prove_ some identity with Mathematica, I usually wonder what their true goal is. Do you simply want to put this identity in Mathematica and let it spit out ``True``, or do you want it to give you a proper, detailed step-by-step proof?

Answer (score 1):

Code to check for a fixed $n$:

```
check[n_]:=With[{
  vars=Table[a[i],{i,1,n}],
  cond=And@@Table[0<=a[i]<=1,{i,1,n}],
  expr=Sum[1/(1+a[i]),{i,1,n}]>=1/2*(n-1)+1/(1+Product[a[i],{i,1,n}])},
  Resolve[ForAll[vars,cond,expr]]];
```

For example

```
AbsoluteTiming[check[2]]
(* {0.012084,True} *)

AbsoluteTiming[check[3]]
(* {0.040185,True} *)

AbsoluteTiming[check[4]]
(* {0.700636,True} *)
```

But already for $n=5$ this did not finish on my machine.

For larger $n$, one could check using random numbers (this could be used to discover counterexamples if there are counterexamples, of course it cannot be used to prove the claim):

```
checkRandomly[n_]:=Sum[1/(1+a[i]),{i,1,n}]>=1/2*(n-1)
 +1/(1+Product[a[i],{i,1,n}])/.Thread[Array[a,n]->RandomInteger[{0,1000},n]/1000]
checkRandomly[n_,repetitions_]:=And@@Table[checkRandomly[n],repetitions];
```

For example

```
AbsoluteTiming[checkRandomly[5,1000]]
(* {0.049084,True} *)

AbsoluteTiming[checkRandomly[10,1000]]
(* {0.093954,True} *)

AbsoluteTiming[checkRandomly[100,1000]]
(* {3.29656,True} *)
```

Here is a proof for all $n$: Write the inequality in the equivalent form
$$
\sum_1^n (\frac{1}{1+a_i} - \frac{1}{2}) \geq \frac{1}{1+\prod_1^n a_i} - \frac{1}{2}
$$
Defining $f(a) = \frac{1}{1+a}-\frac{1}{2}$, the inequality becomes
$$
f(a_1) + \ldots + f(a_n) \geq f(a_1\cdots a_n)
$$
for all $0 \leq a_1,\ldots,a_n \leq 1$.

- To prove the $n=2$ case, use Mathematica:

```
f[a_]:=1/(1+a)-1/2;
Resolve[ForAll[{a,b},And[0<=a<=1,0<=b<=1],f[a]+f[b]>=f[a*b]]]
(* True *)
```

- To prove the $n = 3$ case, use the $n=2$ result twice:
  $$
  f(a_1)+f(a_2)+f(a_3) 
  \geq
  f(a_1) + f(a_2a_3)
  \geq f(a_1a_2a_3)
  $$
  This works since $0 \leq a_2a_3 \leq 1$.
- Similar for higher $n$, simply apply the $n=2$ result multiple times.